# Ordering text output from sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have the following text below:

```
 FLAGS (\Seen \Flagged))
* 1001 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (message-id subject)] {167}
Message-ID: ail test 13
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?RDM=20Request=20RD00001578:=20Under=20Review=20->=20Requested?=

 FLAGS (\Seen \Flagged))
* 1010 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (message-id subject)] {145}
Subject: RE: ail test 12
Message-ID: <81B1DDBBD5E5D148915DBDF77378184D1036F5CD1B@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>


 FLAGS (\Seen \Flagged))
* 1020 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (message-id subject)] {116}
Subject: RE: ail test 14
Message-ID: <8A20A6EF23B11D41A1B3222195A1B2683AD3D013@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

How can I use `sed` or `awk` to get the format to be like this:

```
Subject : the subject
Message-ID: The message ID
```

I know how to fetch the fields, my main problem is to put the desired order where subject must come allways first of message-id.

EDIT:

S.O.  is ( uname -a ) SunOS serverName 5.9 Generic_122300-61 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-15000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in *paragraph* mode (`-00`):

```
perl -00 -lne '
    ($subject) = $_ =~ m/Subject:\s*(.*)/;
    ($message) = $_ =~ m/Message-ID:\s*(.*)/;
    print "Subject: $subject\nMessage-ID: $message"
' input.txt
```

### Output

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?RDM=20Request=20RD00001578:=20Under=20Review=20->=20Requested?=
Message-ID: ail test 13

Subject: RE: ail test 12
Message-ID: <81B1DDBBD5E5D148915DBDF77378184D1036F5CD1B@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>

Subject: RE: ail test 14
Message-ID: <8A20A6EF23B11D41A1B3222195A1B2683AD3D013@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

### Note

From [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) :

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or hexadecimal number.
>   The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.  Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk (for gensub()):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{
    print gensub(/.*\n(Subject[^\n]+).*/,"\\1","")
    print gensub(/.*\n(Message[^\n]+).*/,"\\1","")
}' file
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?RDM=20Request=20RD00001578:=20Under=20Review=20->=20Requested?=
Message-ID: ail test 13
Subject: RE: ail test 12
Message-ID: <81B1DDBBD5E5D148915DBDF77378184D1036F5CD1B@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Subject: RE: ail test 14
Message-ID: <8A20A6EF23B11D41A1B3222195A1B2683AD3D013@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

You can do the same in any awk with match()+substr() or a couple of sub()s instead of gensub().

Comment: Hi Ed, i tried that but its returning : "awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: That means you're using "old, broken awk" ([/usr]/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk because its, well, old and broken. Like I said the solution I posted uses GNU awk (gawk) - I strongly advise you to get that as it has the most useful features of any awk.

Comment: yea,  i noticed after a few tests on other servers. I dont hav admin privileges on the solaris servers to install the new version of awk so i have to stick with that for now =(.

Comment: No, don't do that. Just use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or /bin/nawk instead.

Answer (score 1):

Print values in order:

```
$ awk '/^Subject:/{s=$0}/^Message-ID:/{m=$0}s&&m{print s"\n"m"\n";s=0;m=0}' file
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?RDM=20Request=20RD00001578:=20Under=20Review=20->=20Request...
Message-ID: ail test 13

Subject: RE: ail test 12
Message-ID: <81B1DDBBD5E5D148915DBDF77378184D1036F5CD1B@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...

Subject: RE: ail test 14
Message-ID: <8A20A6EF23B11D41A1B3222195A1B2683AD3D013@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

Comment: Awk works, but now im facing the problem to put it on the Subject/message ID order.

Comment: Hi, tried your cmmand, but im getting : awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Thales you must have a messed up implementation of `awk`. This is using standard `awk` see it working here http://ideone.com/jj8q0C

Comment: @Thales - you're using old, broken awk. See my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `sed` of `awk` if you allow yourself to read the file more than once:

```
grep '^Subject:' your_file | paste -d "\n" - <(grep '^Message-ID' your_file)
```

If you want an empty line between the records:

```
grep '^Subject:' your_file | paste -d "\n" - <(grep '^Message-ID' your_file) | sed -e '3,$s/^Subject:/\n&/'
```

Note that this does not work if the file can change while it is read.

Comment: "No need for `sed` of `awk`" Just `grep` (twice), `paste`, `process substitution` and maybe there is a need for a little bit of `sed`! Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`, which is a little tricky:

```
sed -n -e '/^Subject:/H;/^Message-ID:/H' \
    -e 'x' \
    -e '/\nSubject:.*\n.*/{s/^\n//;p;s/.*//}' \
    -e '/\nMessage-ID:.*\n.*/{s/^\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/;p;s/.*//}' \
    -e 'x' \
    your_file
```

The idea of this script is as follow:

1. Store the lines starting by `Subject:` of `Message-ID:` in the hold space (1st `-e`).
2. Doing # 1 for each line, after reading a record, we will have either `\nSubject:.*\n.*` or `\nMessage-ID:.*\n.*` in the hold space.
3. Working the hold space is then easy to obtain the expected output.